# how can I set clickable the text on a checkbox?

Tags: android, xml, checkbox

I want to create a checkbox for privacy (in a registration form). How can I set the text of the checkbox clickable in oreder to open the certificate of privacy?

Comment: user CheckedTextView instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a neat design, add a **Checkbox** ***without text*** for it. Add a **TextView** to ***immediate right of the Checkbox***. Make sure that you add a underlined text to the TextView. Add a onClickListener to that TextView, which will take the user to another activity, which will display terms and conditions.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can do in different ways: here goes 1

Go to the xml file where you have define the textfield and add the attributes:

```
android:onClick="onClick"
android:clickable="true"
```

So, it will be something like that:

```
<TextView 
       android:id="@+id/click"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"               
       android:text="Click Me"
       android:textSize="55sp"
       android:onClick="onClick"                
       android:clickable="true"/>
```

Then  in your Activity/fragment :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            ... < your code >
          }
```

Other way:

Once you binded the textfield in the activity/fragment:

```
TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById(R.Id.textView1);
```

then set the listener

```
tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
      <your code>
   }
})
```

;

Comment: Defining `onClick` method in XML is a bad practice, use `View.setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener l)` instead.